# HDD making clicking sound every 10s in Win 8.1 - Load/Unload cycle count increasing

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, smart, clicking-sound

I have problem with my Samsung SpinPoint F3 HD103SJ HDDs.
As soon as Win 8.1 loads up, and its in idle, they both make clicking sound every 10seconds.
It sounds like the heads are parking.
I have checked the SMART and each click increases the value of Load/Unload Cycle Count.
There is also a WD HDD connected to my PC, which works fine and doesn't make this sound.
Both of HDDs weren't used much, they have around 80days Power on time. The HDDs are working fine, I can read and write with no issues.

I have ASUS Maximus VII Hero motherboard.
When I open the HD Tune software and leave it open on SMART for the drive, it stops clicking.
It seems to be something in the Windows. When I keep the system at BIOS, it doesn't make this sound.

Could anyone please help me where is the problem? I still have one month of warranty, so I would like to know if I should replace them or not. Thank you.

Comment: Take a back up in case... If in warranty send it back, it isn't normal to make this noise .

Comment: Thank you Dave, well I guess there is nothing else to do.. I will send it back then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue, I fixed this with CrystalDiskInfo:

Goto `Function -> Advanced Feature -> AAM/APM Control`, and I turned off both. This stopped the clicking.

---

This popped up in my notifications as a popular question after almost 5 years.
I forgot to post the answer and nobody answered yet so I thought I would share how I fixed it.